# Unable to sendRedirect() to a jsp page. IllegalStateException

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

Im doing a sample hibernate web app. and my table entries are added to database successfully but im unable to redirect my response to the success page.

Here is the code in my servlet

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        try {
            UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
            userDAO.addUserDetails(userName, password, email, phone, city);
            response.sendRedirect("Success");
            return;
```

My DAO code is as follows

```
Session session = factory.openSession();        
 Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();       
 User user = new User();        
  user.setUserName(userName);
 user.setPassword1(password);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setCity(city);
            user.setPhone(phone);
            session.save(user);
            tr.commit();
        System.out.println("\n\n Details Added \n");
```

Im getting the syso "Details added" in console, but not able to redirect to Success.jsp. Please help as im unable to see where the response is already written to the HTTP

Comment: You're getting an IllegalStateException? What are the details of that?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:482)
 at com.hiberweb.UserController.doPost(UserController.java:29)

Comment: Do you want me to provide the success.jsp page code?

Comment: What is the code prior to the quoted code in your servlet? Something is sending response content before you're calling sendRedirect.

Comment: yes Adrian, i just called super.doPost(req,resp), which in turn written its HTTP already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in the information your provide the response is committed when you call the `sendRedirect` method, if you check the documentation for the method [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) it indicates the reason why you get the exception:

> llegalStateException - If the response was committed or if a partial URL is given and cannot be converted into a valid URL

What it basically means is that you modify the response before you call the `sendRedirect` method, the most common way to modify the response is through the `PrintWriter` `response.getWriter().println`, check your code not modify the response before calling the sendRedirect method.

Comment: Thanks Cesar, as i override using eclipse, it adds automatically the super constructor to the code. Now everything works fine